# Navigation drawer and toolbar appears in splash screen

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am building an app using jetpack navigation with navigation drawer and toolbar, and a splash screen. I set the splash screen fragment to be the entry destination. However when the splash screen starts, the drawer and the toolbar appear on screen.
How to remove them from splash screen but keeping them in all other fragment?
The drawer layout is set in the main activity and it is the navhost

Comment: can you create a new activity to host spashscreen and move rest of your fragments to a different activity which has navigation drawer

Comment: You have to make a Splash screen as Activity

Comment: You should not be using a splash screen fragment, but a [launcher theme](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
I ended up having 2 activities and 2 nav graphs.
The first activity handles the splash screen and the login screen, while the second one handles the rest of the app where the nav drawer should exists.
However by doing this, I ran into another problem where I couldn't clear the splash screen from the backstack as each navgraph has its own stack. To solve this I called the function **finish()** in Activity 1 after calling navController.navigate(R.id.Activity 2) to pop activity 1 from the app's main stack.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate splash activity from others.

Activity 1 -> Splash

Activity 2 -> Navigation Drawer (and all fragments)